# How to read data into combo box from php page using http service for flex spark?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark, flex4.6

> i am trying to put data in to combo box from php page using  http
>   service .there are 2 data  records in the php page but instead of
>   displaying data it displays   [object object] [object object] in the
>   combo box list
>
> here is the mxml code
>
> @namespace s
>   "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";      @namespace mx
>   "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
>                                           {username.text}</username> 
>             {emailaddress.text}</emailaddress>        </s:request>-->
>
> ```
>                   private function send_data():void { 
>           userRequest.send(); 
>                   }           private function send_data1():void { 
>           userRequest.send(); 
>           //testlb.text="testsuccesss";
>                       } 
>               ]]>     </fx:Script>        <s:ComboBox x="197" y="305" width="414" height="32"
>           dataProvider="{userRequest.lastResult.users.user}"
>           labelField="data"   >
>       </s:ComboBox>
>
>
>    </s:View>
> ```

can you help me to indentify the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the property `data` is a string or at least has a sensible `toString()` method?

Comment: yes it is a string @oman Hassan

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your result is coming in XML format, you should use @ before the variable name you use in labelField.

Also, it would be nice to see more code since some of it looks cut off.